# Facebook Graph API Question: How can i get permanent permission/access token to display a public photo album on a webpage?

Tags: ajax, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know it's possible to display public images once I have the access token, but how do I go about getting it? I found the facebook dev docs to be kind've confusing when it comes to extended permissions.

Do i need to somehow register the image gallery/portfolio as an app and have the facebook user who's gallery it is allow it?

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you just need `offline_access` extended permission - then your token will (nearly) never expire

based on 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hurda. From what i just read it seems that i would need to register the galleries i'm building as an app to obtain the access token. I was hoping this would work since my last solution for this problem (Flickr/JSON) ended up being really inconvenient for the client (who's really good at keeping her facebook up to date) and created a ton of extra work for me having to process and upload images to her flickr acct. shoot.

Comment: I'ts not clear from your question - 

You have public gallery as web-application/web-page allready running and tryiing to "push" images on Facebook?

for this pourpose you need register a facebook application - to have own secret and and own app ID

Comment: And if you need to see if you have the offline_access permission, you have it if the expires value in the session is 0.

Comment: Hi @Hurda I know it's a long time ago, but I came across this question because I have a problem with expiration of my access token even if I have my album public and also offline_access. Did I possibly miss something? thanks

Comment: @Arief you probably miss something, bets woudl vbe to start a new question and describe your exact probelm.

Comment: If you're going to use the photos for anything other than "user experience", then you need to ask the user if it is okay.